# Jenkins: stashing iteratively multiple files and unstashing them iteratively throws error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my case, Jenkins build multiple versions of the same binary and then each of the file needs to be made available in another node; for that I'm using stash unstash iteratively but I'm getting this java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException. How can I fix this or any other approach to handle this case?

I've simplified and putting only the needed here:
Tried this:

```
def versionList = ["1", "2", "3"]
versionList().each {
    stage("version"+it) {
        def bPath = "${outputDir}/version${it}"
        dir(bPath){
            stash includes: "*.war", name: 'warFile'
        }
        node("testNode"){
            def warPath = "/home/test/" + "version${it}"
            dir(warPath){
                unstash 'warFile'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried this way:

```
def versionList = ["1", "2", "3"]

node(buildNode){
    versionList().each {
        stage("version"+it) {
            def pwDir = "${outputDir}/version${it}"
            dir(pwDir){
                stash includes: "*.war", name: "warFile${it}"
            }
        }
    }
}
node("testNode"){
    def warPath = "/home/test/"
    versionList().each {
        def fPath = warPath + "version${it}"
        dir(fPath){
            unstash "warFile${it}"
        }
    }
}
```

And in both cases I'm getting this exception:

```
00:27:01  java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/test/version1/abc.war
00:27:01    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
00:27:01    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
00:27:01    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
00:27:01    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
00:27:01    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)
00:27:01    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:220)
00:27:01    at hudson.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:51)
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2853)
00:27:01  Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to testNode
00:27:01        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1797)
00:27:01        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
00:27:01        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
00:27:01        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1165)
00:27:01        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1154)
00:27:01        at hudson.FilePath.untar(FilePath.java:616)
00:27:01        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.StashManager.unstash(StashManager.java:161)
00:27:01        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:77)
00:27:01        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:64)
00:27:01        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
00:27:01        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
00:27:01        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
00:27:01        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
00:27:01        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
00:27:01        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
00:27:01  **Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract warFile1.tar.gz**
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2863)
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath.access$500(FilePath.java:212)
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath$UntarRemote.invoke(FilePath.java:632)
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath$UntarRemote.invoke(FilePath.java:621)
00:27:01    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3329)
00:27:01    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
00:27:01    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
00:27:01    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
00:27:01    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
00:27:01    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
00:27:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
00:27:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
00:27:01    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
00:27:01  Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems iterative stashing/unstashing is  not supported by Jenkins is what I've heard but if that's not the case please update.

In my case what I end up doing was SCP from build node to test node.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).